# Trim in a ForEach query

Tags: powershell, foreach

In my homelab I try to automate scheduled tasks by using PowerShell. I use [System.Collections.Generic.List[String] to collegt a list of all switches for the execution. But I cannot manage to remove the **`** in the last line of my output? Anyone an idea how to solve this issue?

```
-AtLogOn `
-AtStartup `
-Daily `
-DaysInterval 3 `
-DaysOfWeek Sunday, Monday `
-Once `
-RandomDelay (new-Timespan -Minutes 15) `
-RepetitionDuration (new-Timespan -Minutes 15) `
-RepetitionInterval (new-Timespan -Minutes 15) `
-Weekly `
-WeeksInterval 2 `
-At 3am `
```

Here is the code to generate the output:

```
$xml = [xml]@'
<Test>
    <App TaskName = "LAB" Active = "True" >
      <Task Name = "ScheduledTask" Active = "True" Order = "1" Description = "" TaskName = "" Execute = "Powershell.exe" Argument = "-command &amp; D:\ProgramFiles\Tools\Test.ps1 -Application" WorkingDirectory = "" AtLogOn = "1" AtStartup = "1" Daily = "1" DaysInterval = "3" DaysOfWeek = "Sunday, Monday" Once = "1" RandomDelay = "(new-Timespan -Minutes 15)" RepetitionDuration = "(new-Timespan -Minutes 15)" RepetitionInterval = "(new-Timespan -Minutes 15)" Weekly = "1" WeeksInterval = "2" At = "3am" />
    </App>
</Test>
'@


If($($xml.Test.App.Active) -eq "True") {
  ForEach($ActiveTask in $xml.Test.App.Task | Sort-Object Order | Where-Object { $_.Active -eq "True" }){
    Switch($ActiveTask.Name){
      ScheduledTask {
        $TriggerParams = [System.Collections.Generic.List[String]]@()
        If ($TriggerParams.Count -gt 0) { $TriggerParams.Clear() }
        If ($ActiveTask.AtLogOn -eq "1"){
          $TriggerParams.Add($("-" + "AtLogOn" + ' `').Trim())
        }
        If ($ActiveTask.AtStartup -eq "1"){
          $TriggerParams.Add($("-" + "AtStartup" + ' `').Trim())
        }
        If ($ActiveTask.Daily -eq "1"){
          $TriggerParams.Add($("-" + "Daily" + ' `').Trim())
        }
        If ($ActiveTask.DaysInterval -ne ""){
          $TriggerParams.Add($("-" + "DaysInterval " + $ActiveTask.DaysInterval + ' `').Trim())
        }
        If ($ActiveTask.DaysOfWeek -ne ""){
          $TriggerParams.Add($("-" + "DaysOfWeek " + $ActiveTask.DaysOfWeek + ' `').Trim())
        }
        If ($ActiveTask.Once -eq "1"){
          $TriggerParams.Add($("-" + "Once" + ' `').Trim())
        }
        If ($ActiveTask.RandomDelay -ne ""){
          $TriggerParams.Add($("-" + "RandomDelay " + $ActiveTask.RandomDelay + ' `').Trim())
        }
        If ($ActiveTask.RepetitionDuration -ne ""){
          $TriggerParams.Add($("-" + "RepetitionDuration " + $ActiveTask.RepetitionDuration + ' `').Trim())
        }
        If ($ActiveTask.RepetitionInterval -ne ""){
          $TriggerParams.Add($("-" + "RepetitionInterval " + $ActiveTask.RepetitionInterval + ' `').Trim())
        }
        If ($ActiveTask.Weekly -eq "1"){
          $TriggerParams.Add($("-" + "Weekly" + ' `').Trim())
        }
        If ($ActiveTask.WeeksInterval -ne ""){
          $TriggerParams.Add($("-" + "WeeksInterval " + $ActiveTask.WeeksInterval + ' `').Trim())
        }
        If ($ActiveTask.At -ne ""){
          $TriggerParams.Add($("-" + "At " + $ActiveTask.At + ' `').Trim())
        }

        $TriggerParams
        #$TaskTrigger = Invoke-Expression "New-ScheduledTaskTrigger $TriggerParams"

      }
    }
  }
}
```

Cheers, Cpt

Comment: I suggest a different approach: create a hashtable of parameter-name-value pairs that you can pass to `New-ScheduledTaskTrigger` via [splatting](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Splatting). That also allows you to avoid `Invoke-Expression`, which should [_generally_ be avoided](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/powershell/2011/06/03/invoke-expression-considered-harmful/).

Comment: i agree with mklement0 - more specifically, use a parameter splat. you can add/remove/edit each parameter at will. take a look at `Get-Help about_Splatting` for more info. [*grin*]

Answer (score 2):

As [mklement0](https://stackoverflow.com/users/45375/mklement0) already commented, set up a Hashtable and use [Splatting](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Splatting) on cmdlets that take a lot of parameters.

Instead of `$TriggerParams = [System.Collections.Generic.List[String]]@()`, use

```
$TriggerParams = @{}
```

Instead of adding parameters with `` $TriggerParams.Add($("-" + "AtStartup" + ' `').Trim()) ``, use

```
$TriggerParams["AtStartup"] = $true
```

Keep page [New-ScheduledTaskTrigger](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/scheduledtasks/new-scheduledtasktrigger) handy, to see the **types** of the parameters.

| Type | Assign |
| --- | --- |
| SwitchParameter | set it to a boolean `$true` if you want that parameter. Leave it out or set to `$false` otherwise |
| DateTime | a [DateTime] object (like you get with `(Get-Date)`) |
| Int32 | a Signed 32-bit integer (-2147483648..2147483647) |
| UInt32 | an Unsigned 32-bit integer (0..4294967295) |
| DayOfWeek[] | a string array like 'Sunday', 'Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday', 'Thursday', 'Friday', 'Saturday' |
| TimeSpan | a [TimeSpan] object like you get when you subtract two [DateTime] objects from each other or the result of the `New-TimeSpan` cmdlet |

Finally, run the cmdlet with

```
New-ScheduledTaskTrigger @$TriggerParams
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, in your function every instance of your $TriggerParams includes a backtick:

```
$TriggerParams.Add($("-" + "AtLogOn" + ' `').Trim()) 
                                        ^
                                       Here
```

Wouldn't removing this get rid of your problem?

Comment: Unfortunately no. I need this in all lines of the output expect the last one.